# How to check whether the names in file exists in other files in linux?

Tags: linux, grep, search

I usually check whether a specific pattern `Raju` exists in any of the files in a directory like below:

```
grep -E "Raju" *.csv
```

But, now I have a file named `all.csv` that was kept in directory `direct` looks like below:

```
Names
Raju
Madhu
Stephen
Andrea
Markus
```

Directory `direct` looks like below with many files along with `all.csv`

```
direct
  |_____file1.csv
  |_____file2.csv
  |_____file3.csv
  |_____file4.csv
  |_____file5.csv
  |_____all.csv
```

Instead of checking each pattern at once, I would like to check whether the `Names` in `all.csv`exists in which file in the directory `direct`

Let's say for example the `file3` has Raju, Markus, Stephen then it should give output like below:

```
file3.csv: Raju, Markus, Stephen
```

Comment: Does `grep -Ff all.csv *` give you an acceptable output?

Comment: No, it didn't give the desired output.

Comment: Any help please

Comment: Please provide a minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: I have given that above right. what else I can give?

Comment: A couple of input files, or at least `file3.csv`. Should entries with RajuZ be printed, or only exact matches?

Comment: Start with `find direct -type f -name 'file*.csv' | xargs -r grep -Ff direct/all.csv`. Read `man find;man xargs; man grep`.